# how would i put the message from a queue trigger into a database after it has been triggered?

Tags: c#, sql, azure, message-queue, queuetrigger

i am working on a C# project and need help as to how to insert data into the database from the queue trigger, i have a console app that inserts data to the queue on azure and then it gets triggered by the function app, what i don't know how is to add that to a database

so i need to link this to the database and make sure it runs on azure im on the azure but struggling to get it to trigger there as well

```
public class Function1
  {
      [FunctionName("Function1")]
      public void Run([QueueTrigger("part2", Connection = "st10090552connectionstring")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
      {
          
          Console.WriteLine($" messages in queue :" +
              $"" +
              $": {myQueueItem}");
          Console.WriteLine($"function has pulled the data from the queue");
      }
      
  }
```

```
public static void InsertMessage(string Name)
        {
            
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"];

            QueueClient Client = new QueueClient(connectionString, Name);

            // Create the queue if it doesn't already exist
            Client.CreateIfNotExists();
            DateTime date = new DateTime(2021, 12, 31);

            double ID;
            double ID2;
            double barcode;
            string VACCINATIONCENTER;
            string VACCINATIONDATE;
            double VACCINATIONSERIALNUMBER;
            string VACCINATIONCENTER2;
            string VACCINATIONDATE2;



            Console.WriteLine("ENTER YOUR ID");
            string data = Console.ReadLine();
            ID = double.Parse(data);
            Console.WriteLine("ENTER THE VACCINATION CENTER");
            VACCINATIONCENTER = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("ENTER THE VACCINATION DATE");
            VACCINATIONDATE = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("ENTER YOUR SERIAL NUMBER");
            string data1= Console.ReadLine();
           VACCINATIONSERIALNUMBER = double.Parse(data);



            Console.WriteLine("ENTER YOUR BARCODE FOR VACCINES");
            string data2 = Console.ReadLine();
            barcode = double.Parse(data);
            Console.WriteLine("ENTER THE VACCINATION DATE");
            VACCINATIONCENTER2 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("ENTER THE VACCINATION CENTER");
            VACCINATIONDATE2 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("ENTER YOUR ID");
            string data3 = Console.ReadLine();
            ID2  = double.Parse(data);

            var message1  = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ID.ToString() + ":"+ VACCINATIONCENTER +":" + VACCINATIONDATE +":"+VACCINATIONSERIALNUMBER.ToString()));
            var message2 = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(barcode.ToString() + ":" + VACCINATIONCENTER2 + ":" + VACCINATIONDATE2 + ":" + ID2.ToString()));

            Client.SendMessage(message1); ;
                
                Console.WriteLine($"messages saved successfully  ");
            
           
           

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: What kind of database are you using? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @MarkusMeyer it needs to go on azure sql and i have tried to find documentation or methods to do this with no luck , i am stuck on how to get it into the azure sql database

Comment: Not sure on what you are not able to find documentation on. You can instantiate a database connection and add the necessary data into DB using plain ADO code or frameworks like Entity Framework

Comment: @WisdomSeeker from a queue trigger? i should note that i haven't done this before

Comment: Can you please share your current code?

Comment: @MarkusMeyer i added it to the main question

Comment: Can you please check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup